# Integration by parts for covariant tensor fields

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, divergence-operator

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary, and suppose $N$ is the outward unit normal vector field along $\partial M$. I am trying to prove the following integration by parts formula: 
$$
\int_M \langle \nabla F, G \rangle \, dV_g = \int_{\partial M} \left\langle F \otimes N^\flat, G \right\rangle \, dV_{\widehat g} - \int_M \left\langle F, \mathrm{div}\,G\right\rangle \,dV_g
$$
where $F$ is a covariant $k$-tensor field, $G$ is a covariant $(k+1)$-tensor field, and $\mathrm{div}\,G = \mathrm{tr}_g(\nabla G) = \mathrm{tr}\left(\left(\nabla G\right)^\sharp\right)$.

I'm trying to emulate the proof of the more traditional integration by parts formula 
$$
\int_M \left\langle \mathrm{grad}\,u, X \right\rangle \,dV_g = \int_{\partial M} u \left\langle X, N \right\rangle \,dV_{\widehat g} - \int_M u \,\mathrm{div}\,X \, dV_g
$$
which is proven in the following steps:

1. Prove $\iota_{\partial M}^*\left(X ^\big\lrcorner dV_g\right) = \langle X, N \rangle \, dV_{\widehat g}$, where $\iota_{\partial M} : \partial M \hookrightarrow M$ is inclusion and $X^\big\lrcorner dV_g$ denotes interior multiplication;
2. Use this result and Stokes' theorem to prove the divergence theorem:
   $$
   \int_M(\mathrm{div}\,X)\,dV_g = \int_{\partial M} \langle X, N \rangle \, dV_{\widehat g}
   $$
   where the divergence is defined in this case as $(\mathrm{div}\,X)\,dV_g = d\left(X^\big\lrcorner dV_g\right)$;
3. Prove the product rule for the divergence operator: $\mathrm{div}(uX) = u\,\mathrm{div}\,X + \langle \mathrm{grad}\,u, X \rangle$

But I'm not sure what the parallel steps would be. And after taking a closer look, I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way at all, since Stokes' theorem requires the integrand to be a differential form, and I don't see at all how to express the divergence of an arbitrary covariant tensor field as an alternating covariant tensor field. Help on how to begin?

**EDIT:** See comments below for an outline of a solution.

Comment: Can you prove the general formula for the special case that the $M$ is a manifold without boundary?

Comment: If you have the divergence theorem, you don't need to work with differential forms (other than the volume/area forms) at all. You just need to prove a product rule $\mathrm{div}\,\langle F, G \rangle = \langle \nabla F, G \rangle + \langle F ,\mathrm{div}\,G \rangle$ (where the $\langle F,G \rangle$ denotes contraction of $F$ with the first $k$ slots of $G$, producing a $1$-tensor) and apply the divergence theorem to the LHS.

Comment: Okay, I got about that far. Still need to prove a kind of divergence theorem, which I think I can see how to do. When you say $\langle F, G\rangle$ contracts the first $k$ arguments of $F$ with the first $k$ arguments of $G$, I interpreted this a little more formally as $\langle F, G \rangle = \mathrm{tr}^k \left(F^{\sharp k} \otimes G\right)$, where $F^{\sharp k}$ denotes that all $k$ arguments of $F$ have had their indices raised. This worked for me, so I assume this is what you meant?

Comment: I now see that this can be solved using the product rule $$\mathrm{div} \left( \mathrm{tr}^k \left(F^{\sharp k} \otimes G\right)\right) = \langle \nabla F, G \rangle + \langle F, \mathrm{div}\,G\rangle$$ and the identity $$\left\langle \left(\mathrm{tr}^k \left(F^{\sharp k} \otimes G\right)\right)^\sharp, \, N \right\rangle = \left\langle F \otimes N^\flat, G \right\rangle$$ both of which can be proven at each point $p \in M$ in Riemannian normal coordinates. The result follows from the standard divergence theorem for vector fields.